# What's the benefit of using class name to access static methods and static variables in java instead of creating objects and calling them?

Tags: java, static

We use a class's name to access its static methods and variables in java. And accessing static variables and methods using a class name is considered one of the benefits of the static keyword. But how and why is it better than creating an object and then accessing the methods and variables? Does it save space and time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/when-to-use-static-methods)

Comment: @Tom 'Also related' how?